# Can I choose to include/exclude what controller is deployed per environment in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, devops

I would like to expose an endpoint only to certain TEST environment and leave it out altogether in PROD.

I will have a separate `@RestController` for this endpoint.
My question is how to ensure this endpoint is accessible only from the test env and never in production?

I tried to play around with `@ComponentScan`, but didn't get very far.

Comment: I think `@ConditionalOnProperty` would help you

Comment: chekc for env from your properties file ,then --use this `if (env.equals("test")) return redirect` to 404 0r 403

Comment: You can annotate your controller bean with `@Profile` and start dev and test with separate profiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best, easiest and safest solution is to use [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). Use the annotation [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) to specify what environment a certain bean should be created on. Note that if the environment doesn't match the [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) annotation `value`, the bean is not created at all so it doesn't appear in the application container.

Assuming the following `application.properties` files defining the environments you want to hide such REST controller:

- `src/main/resources/application.yml` (general configuration)
- `src/main/resources/application-prod.yml` (production environment)
- `src/main/resources/application-int.yml` (integrationenvironment)

... and these you want to make the REST controller visible for:

- `src/main/resources/application-dev.yml` (development environment)
- `src/main/resources/application-local.yml` (localhost environment)
- `src/test/resources/application-test.yml` (unit/integration tests, note a different folder)

You can configure the REST controller for the lower environments easily. Remember the bean is created if *any* of the listed profiles (environments) is active, therefore understand it as the `or` clause.

```
@Profile({"dev", "local", "test"})
@RestController
public class MyRestController {
    // implementation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a way. basically you can set your environment in the application.properties if i remember right.. then, you can say to the ednpoint "be available only if the environment is dev".

two ways:

1. you create your test endpoint in the test section of the project and use the @Test notation, so if you run the test with maven you only run the test endpoint
2. a normal if condition. 
   If (environment = dev) { you do what you need to test } else { static response saying this is a development endpoint }